# SQL statement in rawquery method not working

Tags: android, database, sqlite

A very simple SQL statement is not working, any ideas?

```
rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + CITY_TABLE + ";", columns);
```

error from stacktrace

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteBindOrColumnIndexOutOfRangeException:
bind or column index out of range: handle 0x19b098006-
```

the rest of the code

```
public ArrayList<String> getCitiesFromCountry(int countryCode){
    String[] columns = new String[]{CITY_NAME};
    ArrayList<String> cityNames = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM  " + CITY_TABLE + ";", columns);

    if (cursor != null){         
      while(cursor.moveToNext()){
         cityNames.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CITY_NAME)));
         ....
      }
      ...
    }
    return cityNames;
}
```

database constants

```
public static final String WORLD_DATABASE = "world_database";
public static final String COUNTRY_TABLE = "country_table";
public static final String CITY_TABLE = "city_table";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String _ID = "_id";
public static final String _ID2 = "_id2";
public static final String COUNTRY_NAME = "country_name";
public static final String CITY_NAME = "city_name";
```

Comment: remove ; from the last in query..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retrieve all columns you dont require that second param in rawquery

```
rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + CITY_TABLE , null);
```

And if you want to retrieve specific rows then use like this...

```
rawQuery("SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM " + CITY_TABLE + " WHERE COL1 = ? AND COL2 = ?", new String[] {"CRUSADER", "CITY"});
```

Answer (score 2):

For raw query, you do not put the columns for the 2nd paramter, as those are for where arguments. ie having a query like

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + CITY_TABLE + " WHERE city_name = ?;", new String[]{"Moon"});
```

If you want to have columns coming from a string array. You can use.

```
db.query(CITY_TABLE, COLUMNS, null, null, null, null, null);
```

This will select the city_table, for the columns

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need `columns` in the statement? You don't need it:

```
rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + CITY_TABLE, null);
```

If you want to pass selection arguments then you should use it. For example, if you want to select only those rows with `city_name = 'New York'`

```
rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + CITY_TABLE + " WHERE " + CITY_NAME + " = ?", new String[] {"New York"});
```

See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You should try removing the ';' sign from the select query 
That's what might be causing the problem,also check the number of column's 
the number of column's might be the cause as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to get the result using either of these two methods
      while(cursor.moveToNext()){
      cityNames.add(cursor.getString(Column_Name);
      or 
      cityNames.add(cursor.getString(ColumnIndex); 
      }
```

and in the raw query you can remove the second argument very well and replace it as null. 
  db.rawQuery("Select * from "+Table_Name,null);